# как вернуть строки кода которые случайно стерлись? то есть как сделать ctrl+z типо в Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

я случайно взаимодействовал какую то комбинацию и мой код просто заменился на 1 строчку вместо 254 положенных

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я исправил хахаха просто надо было нажать на "плюс" (на скриншоте он уже стал "минус")